# Grails How to make address show in two line?

Tags: grails, gsp, grails-controller

I've a student form which there's location inside the form, when I run the app and show the form it'll look like this

> Location : Jl Excel Road Ring No.36 SINGAPORE, 10110

But I want to make the location in two line like this

```
Location : Jl Excel Road Ring No.36
           SINGAPORE, 10110
```

here's the gsp

```
<td><g:message code="location.label"/></td>
<td>${studentInstance.location}</td>
```

and this is the service in def show

```
def loc = Location.findByTidAndDeleteFlag(params.tid, "N")
    if(loc != null){
        studentInstance.location = loc.address1  + " " + loc.city + ", " + loc.zipCode
    }
    else{
        studentInstance.location = ""
    }
```

Comment: add a line break on the service method, i.e. studentInstance.location = loc.address1  + " " + loc.city + ", " + loc.zipCode,  it should be something like: studentInstance.location = loc.address1  + " <br/>" + loc.city + ", " + loc.zipCode
Should solve the prob
:)

Comment: if I add a line break the "<br/>" will be written on the location address 
Jl Orchard Road Ring No.123 <br/> SINGAPORE, 10910

Comment: Not sure but try using this css:
.preformatted {
 white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
 white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
 white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
 white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
 word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
 }
on the same td block, and let see if it can help

Comment: Or you can also add a pre tag, something like this:

<td><pre style="white-space:pre-wrap; border:0px; background-color: #ffffff; font-family: Arial">${studentInstance.location}</pre></td>

Answer (score 1):

Use the *br* tag

```
studentInstance.location = loc.address1  + "<br/> " + loc.city + ", " + loc.zipCode
```

Then you can render directly the HTML unescaped like this:

```
<%=studentInstance.location%>
```

The default codec is probably HTML in your configuration.
Check the value of `grails.views.default.codec`

For more information read this:
http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Plug-ins/codecs.html

I believe that starting from Grails 2.3.x the [default views codec is HTML](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.0.M1/guide/security.html#xssPrevention) with XML escaping in order to prevent XSS attacks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad approach but you can try

`studentInstance.location = loc.address1  + "<br> " + loc.city + ", " + loc.zipCode`

Generally, I would have each of the element of address available in view so that the styling is flexible in view than in controller, something raw would look like:

```
<td><g:message code="location.label"/></td>
<td>${model.address1} <br> ${model.city}, ${model.zipCode}</td>
```

Comment: if I do in gsp like that <td>${studentInstance.address1} <br> ${studentInstance.city}, ${studentInstance.zipCode}</td>, it'll become error because the domain are different location and student ._.

Comment: @airin I meant to set those data in any model and not particularly to any domain class. See my update above.